# URL Normalization - Removing the dot segment

Tags: url, normalization

How would you go about removing the dot segments in a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize URLs by removing the dot-segment, I would use this algorithm prescribed by RFC 3986:

> 5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments
>
> The pseudocode also refers to a "remove_dot_segments" routine for
> interpreting and removing the special "." and ".." complete path
> segments from a referenced path.  This is done after the path is
> extracted from a reference, whether or not the path was relative, in
> order to remove any invalid or extraneous dot-segments prior to
> forming the target URI.  Although there are many ways to accomplish
> this removal process, we describe a simple method using two string
> buffers.
>
> 1. The input buffer is initialized with the now-appended path
>    components and the output buffer is initialized to the empty
>    string.
> 2. While the input buffer is not empty, loop as follows:
>
>    A.  If the input buffer begins with a prefix of "../" or "./",
>    then remove that prefix from the input buffer; otherwise,
>
>    B.  if the input buffer begins with a prefix of "/./" or "/.",
>    where "." is a complete path segment, then replace that
>    prefix with "/" in the input buffer; otherwise,
>
>    C.  if the input buffer begins with a prefix of "/../" or "/..",
>    where ".." is a complete path segment, then replace that
>    prefix with "/" in the input buffer and remove the last
>    segment and its preceding "/" (if any) from the output
>    buffer; otherwise,
>
>    D.  if the input buffer consists only of "." or "..", then remove
>    that from the input buffer; otherwise,
>
>    E.  move the first path segment in the input buffer to the end of
>    the output buffer, including the initial "/" character (if
>    any) and any subsequent characters up to, but not including,
>    the next "/" character or the end of the input buffer.
> 3. Finally, the output buffer is returned as the result of
>    remove_dot_segments.

**Python implementation:**

```
In [36]: path = '/../a/b/../c/./d.html'

In [37]: while '/..' in path:
    pos = path.find('/..')
    pos2 = path.rfind('/',0,pos)
    if pos2 != -1:
        path = path[:pos2]+path[pos+3:]
    else:
        path = path.replace('/..','',1)
   ....:         

In [38]: path = path.replace('/./','/')

In [39]: path = path.replace('/.','')

In [40]: path
Out[40]: '/a/c/d.html'
```

**References:**

- [URL normalization - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization)
- [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4)